# How to extract an xml value that is deep in the xml code

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I am building a product feed and I am having some problems to extract an xml value that lies deep in the xml code.

The XML-code is: (for this question I cleaned the irrelevant values)

```
    <ns2:HotelListResponse xmlns:ns2="http://v3.hotel.wsapi.ean.com/">
    <customerSessionId>0ABAAA78-D672-ED91-3F32-332C20D917D9</customerSessionId>
    <numberOfRoomsRequested>1</numberOfRoomsRequested>
    <moreResultsAvailable>true</moreResultsAvailable>
    <cacheKey>-39d672ed:13f3332c20d:1b00</cacheKey>
    <cacheLocation>10.186.170.120:7300</cacheLocation>
    <HotelList activePropertyCount="1621" size="1">
        <HotelSummary order="0">
            <RoomRateDetailsList>
                  <RoomRateDetails>     
                        <RateInfo rateChange="true" promo="true" priceBreakdown="true">
                                <ChargeableRateInfo total="656.27" surchargeTotal="42.94"         nightlyRateTotal="613.32996" maxNightlyRate="178.42" currencyCode="USD" commissionableUsdTotal="613.32996" averageRate="153.33249" averageBaseRate="170.37251">
                        </RateInfo>
                 </RoomRateDetails>
            </RoomRateDetailsList>
        </HotelSummary>
    </HotelList>
    </ns2:HotelListResponse>
```

The php code I use:

```
    <?php
    $post_string ='type=xml';
    $post_string .= '&cid=55505';
    $post_string .= '&minorRev=24';
    $post_string .= '&apiKey=wwfzhd95v9vtzh4jc8yjcug9';
    $post_string .= '&locale=nl_NL';
    $post_string .= '&currencyCode=EUR';
    $post_string .= '&customerIpAddress=10.184.2.9';
    $post_string .= '&customerUserAgent=Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1)+AppleWebKit        /535.11+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/17.0.963.79+Safari        /535.11';
    $post_string .= '&customerSessionId=';
    $post_string .= '&xml=';
    $post_string .= '<HotelListRequest>';
    $post_string .= '<arrivalDate>$checkindate</arrivalDate>';
    $post_string .= '<departureDate>$checkoutdate</departureDate>';
    $post_string .= '<RoomGroup>';
    $post_string .= '<Room>';
    $post_string .= '<numberOfAdults>2</numberOfAdults>';
    $post_string .= '</Room>';
    $post_string .= '<Room>';
    $post_string .= '<numberOfAdults>$adultcount</numberOfAdults>';
    $post_string .= '<numberOfChildren></numberOfChildren>';
    $post_string .= '</Room>';
    $post_string .= '</RoomGroup>';
    $post_string .= '<latitude>';
    $post_string .= $lat; 
    $post_string .= '</latitude>';
    $post_string .= '<longitude>';
    $post_string .= $long; 
    $post_string .= '</longitude>';
    $post_string .= '<searchRadius>30</searchRadius>';
    $post_string .= '<searchRadiusUnit>km</searchRadiusUnit>';
    $post_string .= '<minStarRating>';
    $post_string .= $ratingmin;
    $post_string .= '</minStarRating>';
    $post_string .= '<maxStarRating>';
    $post_string .= $ratingmax;
    $post_string .= '</maxStarRating>';
    $post_string .= '<minRate>';
    $post_string .= $minprice;
    $post_string .= '</minRate>';
    $post_string .= '<maxRate>';
    $post_string .= $maxprice;
    $post_string .= '</maxRate>';
    $post_string .= '<tripAdvisorRatingUrl>';
    $post_string .= $mintripadvisorarray;
    $post_string .= '</tripAdvisorRatingUrl>';
    $post_string .= '<countryCode>FR</countryCode>';
    $post_string .= '<supplierCacheTolerance>MED_ENHANCED</supplierCacheTolerance>';
    $post_string .= '<sort>';
    $post_string .= $sort;
    $post_string .= '</sort>';
    $post_string .= '<numberOfResults>10</numberOfResults>';
    $post_string .= '</HotelListRequest> ';

    $path = "http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list"; //Relative path to the file with $_POST parsing
    $ch = curl_init($path); 
    $fp = fopen('data.xml','w');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string); //Send the data to the file
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/xml')); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    $val = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);//Close curl session
    fclose($fp); //Close file overwrite

    //Use Curl to get XML here.

    $data = simplexml_load_file('data.xml');

    //Uncomment this to view the parsed XML on screen.
    /*
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($data->HotelList);
    echo '</pre>';
    */

    echo "<ul id=\"data\">\n";
    $resultnumber = 0;
    foreach($data->HotelList->HotelSummary as $info):

$resultnumber++;
$title=$info->name;
$add=$info->address1;
$city=$info->city;
$locationdescription=$info->locationDescription;
$locationdescription = lcfirst($locationdescription);
$count=$data->HotelList['activePropertyCount'];
$thumbnail1=$info->thumbNailUrl;
$thumbnail2= "http://images.travelnow.com";
$thumbnail = $thumbnail2.$thumbnail1;
$image = substr_replace($thumbnail, 'l', -5, -4);
$image1 = substr_replace($thumbnail, 'n', -5, -4);
$image2 = substr_replace($thumbnail, 'g', -5, -4);
$image3 = substr_replace($thumbnail, 'd', -5, -4);
$image4 = substr_replace($thumbnail, 'y', -5, -4);
$image5 = substr_replace($thumbnail, 'z', -5, -4);
$chargerate= $data->RoomRateDetailsList->RoomRateDetails->RateInfo->ChargeableRateInfo['total'];
$highrate=$info->highRate;
$prijs= round($highrate,0);
$deeplink=$info->deepLink;
$hotelrating=$info->hotelRating;
$hotelratinground = round($hotelrating,0);
$tripadvisorratingurl=$info->tripAdvisorRatingUrl;
$distance =$info->proximityDistance; 
$distanceround= round($distance,0);
$chargeableRateInfo = $rateInfo->ChargeableRateInfo['total'];

echo 
   "<li>
        <time> <i>Hotel ",$resultnumber,"  van ",$count,"</i> </time>                         
        <div class=\"title\"><b> ",$title," <img src='../pics/",$hotelratinground,"-star-rating.png' width='100' height='20'></b></div>
        <div class=\"artist\">Adres: ",$add,"</div>
        <div class=\"locatie\">Locatie: ",$city,", ",$locationdescription,"</div>
        <div class=\"image\"><img src=$image /></div>
        <div class=\"prijs\">Prijs: €",$chargerate,"</div>
        <div class=\"deeplink\"><a href=",$deeplink,">Bekijk aanbieding</a></div>
        <div class=\"hotelrating\"> ",$hotelrating," sterren</div>
        <div class=\"tripadvisorratingurl\"><img src=$tripadvisorratingurl/> ",$tripadvisorratingurl," </div>
        <div class=\"distance \"> Afstand: ",$distanceround," km </div><br>                       
   </li>\n";

    endforeach;

    echo "</ul>";


    ?>
```

All code is working fine and doing as supposed to do.
Execpt the line:

```
    $chargerate= $data->RoomRateDetailsList->RoomRateDetails->RateInfo->ChargeableRateInfo['total'];
```

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The first thing you might do wrong is not to look for errors, see: [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14504459/367456). The next thing you might do wrong is not to look into existing material which normally explains how things are done, shows alternative ways and provides working examples. See [Basic SimpleXML usage](http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic) and the many other and related questions here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
$chargerate= $data->RoomRateDetailsList->RoomRateDetails->RateInfo->ChargeableRateInfo['total'];
```

use

```
$chargerate= $info->RoomRateDetailsList->RoomRateDetails->RateInfo->ChargeableRateInfo['total'];
             ^^^^^
```

The `$data` contains whole response while You need to be within a concrete `$data->HotelList->HotelSummary` which is in the `$info` from the `foreach()` loop.

Also the line

```
$chargeableRateInfo = $rateInfo->ChargeableRateInfo['total'];
```

looks suspicious as the variable `$rateinfo` is not set anywhere and it should refer to `$info->RoomRateDetailsList->RoomRateDetails->RateInfo`...

Comment: The line "$chargeableRateInfo = $rateInfo->ChargeableRateInfo['total'];" was a trial line, indeed with no reference in $rateinfo. I deleted it

Comment: I tried replacing $data into $info. Unfortunately this did not work out.

Comment: I also added an error reporting line to the php code. This reports the error: 
"Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in homepage/includes-hotel/xml_parser.php on line 100" Line 100 is the line "$chargerate= $info->RoomRateDetailsList->...."

Comment: This may occure if some `HotelSummary` does not have it's children... Or I don't know... Maybe You should post here whole XMl file... You are addressing many XML tags/properties that are not present in Your example...

Comment: The problem was not in the foreach loop, but in the line $post_string .= '<arrivalDate>$checkindate</arrivalDate>';  Apperently this should be like     $post_string .= '<arrivalDate>';
    $post_string .= $checkindate;
    $post_string .= '</arrivalDate>';
Same for some other variables.

Nevertheless tanks very much for your help!

Comment: So the problem was caused in the first part when creating the XML for request, not within the response? Strange... You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The full xml code:

```
<ns2:HotelListResponse xmlns:ns2="http://v3.hotel.wsapi.ean.com/">
<customerSessionId>0ABAAA88-25AD-1A91-3F32-88C0FB6909EC</customerSessionId>
<numberOfRoomsRequested>1</numberOfRoomsRequested>
<moreResultsAvailable>true</moreResultsAvailable>
<cacheKey>-5825ad1a:13f388c0fb6:-7b1</cacheKey>
<cacheLocation>10.186.170.136:7300</cacheLocation>
<HotelList activePropertyCount="1620" size="1">
<HotelSummary order="0">
<hotelId>391066</hotelId>
<name>Hotel Paradis</name>
<address1>41 Rue Des Petites Ecuries</address1>
<city>Paris</city>
<postalCode>75010</postalCode>
<countryCode>FR</countryCode>
<airportCode>BVA</airportCode>
<supplierType>E</supplierType>
<propertyCategory>1</propertyCategory>
<hotelRating>3.0</hotelRating>
<confidenceRating>96</confidenceRating>
<amenityMask>0</amenityMask>
<tripAdvisorRating>2.0</tripAdvisorRating>
<locationDescription>In Gare du Nord - Gare de l&apos;Est in Parijs</locationDescription>
<shortDescription>&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;Ligging.&lt;/b&gt; &lt;br /&gt;Hotel Paradis bevindt zich in Gare du Nord - Gare de l&apos;Est in Parijs, dicht bij Folies Bergères, Musée du Louvre en Notre-Dame van Parijs. Andere bezienswaardigheden in de</shortDescription>
<highRate>199.12</highRate>
<lowRate>145.6</lowRate>
<rateCurrencyCode>USD</rateCurrencyCode>
<latitude>48.8739</latitude>
<longitude>2.34994</longitude>
<proximityDistance>3.2130618</proximityDistance>
<proximityUnit>MI</proximityUnit>
<hotelInDestination>true</hotelInDestination>
<thumbNailUrl>/hotels/1000000/10000/6200/6147/6147_43_t.jpg</thumbNailUrl>
<deepLink>http://travel.ian.com/index.jsp?pageName=hotAvail&amp;cid=55505&amp;hotelID=391066&amp;mode=2&amp;numberOfRooms=1&amp;room-0-adult-total=2&amp;room-0-child-total=0&amp;arrivalMonth=6&amp;arrivalDay=8&amp;departureMonth=6&amp;departureDay=12&amp;showInfo=true&amp;locale=nl_NL</deepLink>
<RoomRateDetailsList>
<RoomRateDetails>
<roomTypeCode>200103873</roomTypeCode>
<rateCode>201121699</rateCode>
<maxRoomOccupancy>2</maxRoomOccupancy>
<quotedRoomOccupancy>2</quotedRoomOccupancy>
<minGuestAge>0</minGuestAge>
<roomDescription>Standaard, lits-jumeaux - Non Refundable</roomDescription>
<promoId>202564842</promoId>
<promoDescription>10% korting op dit verblijf!</promoDescription>
<currentAllotment>1</currentAllotment>
<propertyAvailable>true</propertyAvailable>
<propertyRestricted>false</propertyRestricted>
<expediaPropertyId>6147</expediaPropertyId>
<rateKey>0ABAAA88-25AD-1A91-3F32-88C0FB6907B0</rateKey>
<RateInfo rateChange="true" promo="true" priceBreakdown="true">
<ChargeableRateInfo total="659.12" surchargeTotal="43.11" nightlyRateTotal="616.01" maxNightlyRate="179.21" currencyCode="USD" commissionableUsdTotal="616.01" averageRate="154.0025" averageBaseRate="171.11499">
<NightlyRatesPerRoom size="4">
<NightlyRate promo="true" rate="145.6" baseRate="161.78"></NightlyRate>
<NightlyRate promo="true" rate="145.6" baseRate="161.78"></NightlyRate>
<NightlyRate promo="true" rate="179.21" baseRate="199.12"></NightlyRate>
<NightlyRate promo="true" rate="145.6" baseRate="161.78"></NightlyRate>
</NightlyRatesPerRoom>
<Surcharges size="1">
<Surcharge amount="43.11" type="TaxAndServiceFee"></Surcharge>
</Surcharges>
</ChargeableRateInfo>
</RateInfo>
<ValueAdds size="1">
<ValueAdd id="2048">
<description>Gratis draadloos internet</description>
</ValueAdd>
</ValueAdds>
</RoomRateDetails>
        </RoomRateDetailsList>
        </HotelSummary>
    </HotelList>
</ns2:HotelListResponse>
```

The updated error line after your previous comments:

```
$chargerate= $info->RoomRateDetailsList->RoomRateDetails->RateInfo->ChargeableRateInfo['total'];
```